# php post request and redirection

Tags: php

I'm creating a page where the `add_user.php` page is supposed to log you in afterwards

The `login.php` page uses the:

```
$_POST['username']
$_POST['password']
```

To authenticate and log you in, it also fills out plenty of session variables which I do not want to recalculate

I want the `add_user.php` to login after inserting into the database.

Here are the final bits of code that are not performing the function I'm after:

```
$_SESSION["username"] = $username;
$_SESSION["password"] = $password;
header("location:dashboard.php");
```

I want to use `$username` and `$password` and pass them to the `login.php` page.

Comment: Didn't understand. Please elaborate.

Comment: Setting a location header will cause the browser to make a GET request, There is no header that can instigate a POST. There are numerous ways you can complete your task (Have Login accepts GET parameters, `include` login withing add_user, perform the redirect with javascript form submit) - for a proper answer you will need to edit your question to include a lot more details

Comment: Why don't you pass the variables to `login.php` using the `html` form `method="post"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are a lot of ways to do that, the most simple ones are

1 Create a session key(stored in the db per session and user), set it by writing it into something like $_SESSION['sKey'], and on the page you want to be logged in do something like:

```
 if (isset($_SESSION['sKey'])){
    $validLogin = check_sKey_from_DB($_SESSION['sKey']); //previously created function that checks, if the key is present in the DB and still valid...
    if($validLogin){
     //you are logged in
    }
 }
```

in the DB you should have something like:

```
 Table(sessions): 
 userid(foreignkey)|loggedin(date)|sessionid(randomly generated Number)|validthrou(date)
```

2 pass e.g. GET attributes with the header, something like:

```
 header("Location:index.php?user=mustermann&pass=123")
```

3. or just set the Session, and check for that...

Comment: I would never advise having the password of any sort in plaintext in the GET url request

Answer (score 0):

Useing PHP `SESSION` superglobal array you need to start `SESSION` at the very beginning of the `<?php ?>` portion.

See the example-

```
<?php
session_start();  //session is started here just the next line of <?php
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
$_SESSION['password'] = $password;

?>
```

Now this session variables may be used any other pages say add_user.php page.

Comment: I have:
if (empty($_SESSION["username"])) {//not a new user
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    header("location:loggedin.php");
  }

to test, unfortunately I never get redirected

Comment: Your question is not so clear to me. You have the problem in the header() function? 
If just the header() function not works then I suggest you an effective process.
Use <script>
Like that-
<script>
window.location.href="loggedin.php";
</script>

Answer (score -1):

Keep in mind to start session before setting any value of global variable `$_SESSION`

`session_start();` is used to start a session.